# django rest framework process

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm starting out with Django Rest Framework but I am confused as to how the DRF works.
URL -> ASSIGNED VIEWSET -> DATABASE -> DJANGO ORM -> MODEL -> VIEW -> output
but where does serializer get executed? I know that it turns DATABASE objects into JSON but I don't know when serializer gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to double-check that you know this: the `Serializer` class serializes an object instance. Let's say I have this object:

```py
from datetime import datetime

class Comment(object):
    def __init__(self, email, content, created=None):
        self.email = email
        self.content = content
        self.created = created or datetime.now()

# Remember to instantiate
comment = Comment(email='leila@example.com', content='foo bar')
```

and then the `serializer` will transform it into

```
{'email': 'leila@example.com', 'content': 'foo bar', 'created': '2016-01-27T15:17:10.375877'}
```

**So when will this be called?** Anywhere + anytime you created an object that belongs to this class (e.g. view, form, backend handles, etc), the serializer will be executed, albeit you have to separately call the serializer like `serializer = CommentSerializer(comment)`.